# AmCharts timestamp data points are formatted to nearest day

Tags: amcharts

So my dateFormat is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" which I think causes my data points to be rounded to the day.

```
var chart = am4core.createFromConfig({

  // Category axis
  "xAxes": [{
    "type": "DateAxis",
        "renderer": {
      "labels": {
        "location": 0.0001
      }
    },
    "dateFormats": {
        "dateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  }
  }],
```

Image that shows the issue I have

```
Timestamp format: 2016-12-08 14:00:43

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhhbn.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`inputDateFormat`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateformatter/#inputDateFormat_property) to [parse your date+timestamp format](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Parsing_dates_in_data). By default it is set to parse daily data (`yyyy-MM-dd`), which is why your data is clustered together.

```
am4core.createFromConfig({
  // ...
  dateFormatter: {
    inputDateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
    // ...
  },
  // ...
```

Comment: Something so simple, makes such a huge difference. Thank you